# TemplateDoesNotExist at / error, even though index.html exists in the stated folder

Tags: django, view, python-3.6

Following up on [https://realpython.com/location-based-app-with-geodjango-tutorial/] and implementing the nearby shops app. However getting a TemplateDoesNotExist at/, even though the file exists in the stated folder.

Tried out solutions:

1. Created subdirectory(templates) in the 'shops' app
2. Changed DIRS in settings.py

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [''],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

## Also, Template postmortem states:

Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

```
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/username/sampleShops/nearbyshops/nearbyshops/shops (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/nearbyshops/shops (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/nearbyshops/shops (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/templates/nearbyshops/shops (Source does not exist)
```

`
Moreso, I am not working in a virtual env(if that makes a difference, although it shouldn't)

Comment: Is your app containing template in INSTALLED_APP?

Comment: yes, it is in INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score 0):

Change in `TEMPLATES`

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Then keep template inside `templates` directory.

```
your_app/
    models/
    temapltes/
        app_name/
            your_template.html
```

Comment: /home/username/sampleShops/nearbyshops/shops/templates. This is the location of my template but the error persists.

Comment: This is my current file structure:
sampleShop/
    nearbyshops/
      nearbyshops/
          settings.py
          urls.py
          template/
              index.html
      shops/
         admin.py
         models.py
         apps.py
         views.py
         tests.py
      manage.py
`
This is how I am calling : template_name = "nearbyshops/". This is being called from views in the shops/ folder.

Comment: Then how you return template name from view

Comment: Well, it worked, created a template folder inside shops/ and then added index.html to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try replace 'DIRS' with:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Don’t forget to have /templates folder in the same path of your settings file.

Comment: settings file is in nearbyshops, whereas my current template folder is in nearbyshops/shops/templates. Are you suggesting that I change the location of the template folder or instead change the path in DIRS?

Comment: I tried the above with the location of my templates folder same as my settings.py file. However the error persists. Moreover, the error shows that django is unable to find shops/shop_list.html, when there's no mention of the file called shop_list.html anywhere(did a grep search). Instead of shop_list.html it should be looking for index.html.

Comment: If error said can’t find a filename is because your first problem is already solved, your directory was found, please copy your view to see how you called the template